# how to rotate vector / time series

Tags: r, rotation

I have for example such a vector `y`

```
y <- c(1,7,4,8,4,6,1)
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) # indexes
```

I would like to rotate a vector by an arbitrary number of degrees.

input vector --> rotation function --> rotated vector.

Something like this
[image]

I found a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069790/rotate-a-time-series-with-constraints-for-start-and-end), but I'm not good at formulas, can someone give an example with code

Comment: Your picture implies a 2D space and that suggests to me you'd need two vectors to describe the point coordinates. Can you explain more?

Comment: The image is just for a better example.
I added a second vector of coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sf`:

- create a curve as `linestring`
- create a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)
- multiply the curve by the rotation matrix

```r
library(sf)

x <- c(1,7,4,8,4,6,1)
curve <- st_linestring(cbind(1:length(x), x))  


theta <- pi / 3
rotation <- matrix(c(cos(theta),sin(theta),-sin(theta),cos(theta)),ncol =2)
plot(curve)
```

[image]

```r
plot(curve*rotation)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need, but can I convert the (curve * rotation) back to a vector or matrix?

Comment: `st_coordinates(curve*rotation)`

Comment: note that you can also translate by `curve+ c(translationx,translationy)`

Answer (score 1):

With {tidyverse} and {spdep}.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(spdep)

y <- c(1,7,4,8,4,6,1)
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

base <- data.frame(x,y)

rotated <- 
  data.frame(x = x, y = y) %>% 
  spdep::Rotation(angle = 0.5) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% rename(x = 1, y = 2)

bind_rows(base %>% mutate(id = "base"),
          rotated %>% mutate(id = "rotated")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = id)) +
    geom_path()
```

[image]

Created on 2021-04-23 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)